# Compiz widget layer interferes with libnotify notifications

Tags: compiz, notification, notify-osd, libnotify

I use the Compiz Widget Layer plugin so as to have a fullscreen Terminator window a keystroke away. The only issue I have is, when I'm in the Widget Layer, notifications don't appear, so I don't come to know when someone sends me an IM in Pidgin. Does anyone have a solution that can make libnotify notifications appear in the Widget Layer?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem or are you still looking for help? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I'd forgotten about this :). I've answered the question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that libnotify is [designed in such a way as to not disturb users when they're using a fullscreen application](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2007/05/15/any-tips-for-libnotify-trouble/), and that does make sense from a design point of view. So instead of using Terminator fullscreen, I got rid of its titlebar using the "Window Rules" plugin. This way it looks like it's fullscreen, and I also receive notifications properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution, but I have not tested it so you will have to comment and tell me if it works.

Add (title=notify-osd) to your Widget Layer match option as follows:
[image]

In light of your comment (that this does not seem to work), I suggest reporting a bug against compiz. (`ubuntu-bug compiz`).

Comment: It doesn't work. I have a new theory: I think the problem is that I've set the Terminator window to fullscreen using Window Rules, and *that* is what's causing notifications to not appear, not the Widget Layer. If that's true, is there a solution to it? What do you think?